# How to include blocks of code

Tags: php, templates, symfony

I'm building a little blog engine, and I'm stuck on something : I want to be able to add blocks of code in my blog posts, just like "templates" on Wikipedia.

Some of these templates are a little complex, and require some code. What is the best practice in such a case ? I don't think I should put php code in the database, right ?

No matter how I look at it there's a disconnect between what templates will be available and the database. I couldn't create a dropdown list of templates, or could I ?

Comment: to answer your last point: you're right. Executable code should never be in the database. Not even if it seems like a 'clever' solution.

Comment: why don't you use templates in twig? It's dynamic and you can include it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Including other Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates) in the symfony documentation. If you need to add code to your included templates you should [Embed Controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers).

Hope it helps.